# Video recording is too fast

Tags: c++, opencv, video, image-processing

Please have a look at the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

double getMSE(const Mat& I1, const Mat& I2);

int main()
{
    Mat current;
    VideoCapture cam1;
    VideoWriter *writer = new VideoWriter();



    cam1.open(0);

    namedWindow("Normal");

    if(!cam1.isOpened())
    {
        cout << "Cam not found" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    cam1>>current;
    Size *s = new Size((int)current.cols,current.rows);
    writer->open("D:/OpenCV Final Year/OpenCV Video/MyVideo.avi",CV_FOURCC('D','I','V','X'),10,*s,true);


    while(true)
    {
        //Take the input
        cam1 >> current;

        *writer << current;
        imshow("Normal",current);

        if(waitKey(30)>=0)
         {
               break;
         }


    }
}
```

This code runs fine, no issue. But, when I run the recorded video, it is super fast! Like it is fast forwarded. I really do not understand why.

Comment: So some frames are  omited when saving?

Comment: What is "run" FPS? If it is 24 and you are saving with 10, then it is fast forwarded by 2.4 multiplier.

Comment: Are you sure that the output video framerate is the same as the webcam recording framerate?  It's possible that you're saving all the frames correctly, but have the output framerate set incorrectly.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik - I think you mean the other way around.  If the webcam is 24 FPS and you playback at 10 FPS, you're playing at 10/24 speed (< 1.0x)

Comment: @GigaWatt writer->open() has 10 fps as argument (so is saving as 10 fps) and the playback fps is probably bigger fps defined in it.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik: I am sorry, I did not understand

Comment: @Knight what instruction are you using to wait between showing frames? I dont see anything for that. If you can draw a frame in 1 ms, then you need to wait for 32ms between frames to get 33FPS for example.

Comment: According to your description, recording is not fast but slow so that when you play, it looks like fast forwarding. This is typical with good webcam or video camera because you are breaking every image grabbing by showing it per frame. Try not to imshow and see what happens.

Comment: @Thomas: Thank you for the reply. But, it made it super fast!

Comment: Have you tried different values for `double fps`? Do you have the same results if fps=20 instead of 10?

Comment: What about a different coder? CV_FOURCC('X','V','I','D') or CV_FOURCC('D','I','V','3')?

Answer (score 2):

Check the rate at which you grab frames from the camera and make sure that this rate matches the rate at which you record the frames into the output file.

The frame rate for writing to a file is specified as `fps` argument to [this function](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=videowriter#bool%20VideoWriter%3a%3aopen%28const%20string&%20filename,%20int%20fourcc,%20double%20fps,%20Size%20frameSize,%20bool%20isColor%29):

```
bool VideoWriter::open(const string& filename, int fourcc, 
           double fps, Size frameSize, bool isColor=true);
```

As for the camera fps, for some cameras you can determine its frame rate [as follows](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=videocapture#double%20VideoCapture%3a%3aget%28int%20propId%29)

```
double fps = cam1.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
```

Or if the camera doesn't support this method you can find its frame rate by measuring average delay between consecutive frames.

**Update:** If you camera doesn't support `cam1.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);`, the frame rate can be estimated experimentally. Like this for example:

```
while(true) {
    int64 start = cv::getTickCount();

    //Grab a frame
    cam1 >> current;

    if(waitKey(3)>=0) {
        break;
    }

    double fps = cv::getTickFrequency() / (cv::getTickCount() - start);
    std::cout << "FPS : " << fps << std::endl;
}
```

Also, make sure the output video file is open for writing

```
if ( !writer->isOpened())
{
    cout  << "Could not open the output video for write: " << endl;
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Your camera probably doesn't support this method. You estimate the camera frame rate by measuring average frame rate experimentally. For example using OpenCV commands like `cv::getTickCount();` and `cv::getTickFrequency()`

Comment: and...? is video file opens for writing ok? maybe try different codec as suggested above.

Comment: did. Tried both..ohh, still the same :(

Comment: did you match writing fps to camera fps?